# Python mysql select field based on variable

Tags: python, mysql

I want to create a MySQL syntax to select a field based on a variable, what I have is:

```
book_category = "science"
mycursor_a.execute(("SELECT {book_categories} FROM research_papers WHERE book_Name = %s", (book,)).format(book_categories = book_category))
```

but I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because

> (book,))

is a tuple and not an object, remember that tuples don't have dynamic reading like an object or dictionary.

To solve that we need a dictionary variable as a result.

can be achieved by setting the cursor.

```
mycursor_a= db.cursor( buffered=True , dictionary=True)
book_category = "science"
mycursor_a.execute(("SELECT {book_categories} FROM research_papers WHERE book_Name = %s", (book,)).format(book_categories = book_category))
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi the reason it is not working becuase

```py
("SELECT {book_categories} FROM research_papers WHERE book_Name = %s", (book,))
```

is considered as tuple (instead of string) and to avoid that you can use `book` same as you used  `book_categories`

so here is my proposed solution to your value

```py
book_category = "science"
book = "your value"
mycursor_a.execute("SELECT {book_categories} FROM research_papers WHERE book_Name = {variable}" ).format(book_categories = book_category ,  variable = book )
```